# Times return value 0 in Linux C

Tags: c, linux

I begin learn about the Linux C,but i meet the problem so confused me.
I use the function `times`.but return the value equals 0.
ok i made the mistak,I changed the code:
But the is not much relative with printf. clock_t is define with long in Linux.so i convert clock_t to long.
This is my code:

```
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   long clock_times;
   struct tms begintime;
   sleep(5);
   if((clock_times=times(&begintime))==-1)
      perror("get times error");
   else
   {
      printf("%ld\n",(long)begintime.tms_utime);
      printf("%ld\n",(long)begintime.tms_stime);
      printf("%ld\n",(long)begintime.tms_cutime);
      printf("%ld\n",(long)begintime.tms_cstime);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

the output:
0
0
0
0
the also return 0;
and I using gdb to debug,Also the variable of begintimes also to be zero.
there is no relative with `printf` function.
Please

Comment: Your `printf` is using floating point format `%f`, but the time is a `long` integer. Try using `%ld` (long integer) instead of `%f` (float).

Comment: ... and turn some warnings on.  Your compiler will tell you the problem immediately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do the first and the third printf work so differently?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514395/why-do-the-first-and-the-third-printf-work-so-differently)

Comment: I made the mistake in first printf.I changed.but there is no relative with the printf,i just wonder why using `times`.the struct variable is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not unusual; the process simply hasn't used enough CPU time to measure.  The amount of time the process spends in `sleep()` doesn't count against the program's CPU time, as `times()` measures *The CPU time charged for the execution of user instructions* (among other related times) which is the amount of time the process has spent executing user/kernel code.

Change your program to the following which uses more CPU and can therefore be measured:

```
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   long clock_times;
   struct tms begintime;
   unsigned i;

   for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
      time(NULL);    // An arbitrary library call

   if((clock_times=times(&begintime))==-1)
      perror("get times error");
   else
   {
      printf("%ld %ld %ld %ld\n",
        (long)begintime.tms_utime,
        (long)begintime.tms_stime,
        (long)begintime.tms_cutime,
        (long)begintime.tms_cstime);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code using close to none CPU time, so results are correct. Sleep suspends your program execution - everything that happens in this time is not your execution time, so it wouldn't be counted.

Add empty loop and you'll see the difference. (ofc., disable compiler optimisations - or empty loop will be removed).

Take a look at 'time' program output (time ./a.out) - it prints 'real' time (estimated by gettimeofday(), i suppose), user time (time wasted by your userspace code) and system time (time wasted within system calls - e.g. write to file, open network connection, etc.).

(sure, by 'wasted' i mean 'used', but whatever)